# Second order autonomous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am looking for a periodic solution (with period $2\pi m$, for some integer $m$) to the following ODE $$\ddot{x}+x-\frac{1}{x}=0.$$ ($x(t)=\pm 1$ trivially solves this equation). Note that this system is integrable, so the quantity $$E=\dot{x}^2+x^2-\log x^2$$ is constant for any solution. Separating variables and integrating gives $$t=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{E-x^2+\log x^2}}.$$ However, I haven't been able to solve the integral. Maybe thinking of this as a physical system with potential $V(x)=x^2-\log x^2$ would be useful (though I haven't been able to employ this fact).

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I do believe your equation for $E$ is incorrect. Please check. I think the first term should be $2\dot{x}$.

Comment: Wait, hold on.  You are integrating these with respect to $t$, not $x$. The $x$ is in fact a function, not a variable, right?  So your entire equation for $E$ is invalid.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum:  Everything is O.K.: differentiate $E$ with respect to $t$.  $E$ is a Hamilton function.

Comment: Okay. I will take your word for it.  It must be beyond my knowledge then. Cant really help.

Comment: Are you trying to find explicit solution? Or do you just want to show that it exists?

Comment: Regarding the existence alone of periodic solutions, it appears that it can be proved. The equation is equivalent to $$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=y\\ \dot{y}=-x+\frac{1}{x},\end{cases}$$ which is a Hamiltonian system, with $H(x,y)=\frac12y^2+\frac12x^2-\frac12\log{x^2}$. Take the equilibrium $(1,0)$. It is a nondegenerate critical point of $H$, with Hessian matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1,2)$, hence positive definite. By the [Morse lemma](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Morse_lemma), there is a nbhd of $(1,0)$ foliated by level sets of $V$, homeomorphic to circle (hence periodic orbits).

Comment: The above reasoning gives no information on the period of those solutions.  The linearization of the system at $(0,1)$ has eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{2}i$, so one would rather expect solutions of period $\sqrt{2}\pi$ (at least with small amplitude).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to conclude the existence of closed orbits due to the energy formula structure.

The energy level contour lines are given by

$$
\dot x^2+x^2-\log(x^2) = E
$$

Near the minimum they have the aspect

[image]

In red is shown the level $E = 4$ and in green an orbit described for $x_0 = 0.15, \dot x_0 = 0$.

Following, in red the plot for $\dot x$ and in blue the plot for $x$

[image]
I hope this helps.